# R: collapse two time series to create vectors containing only the points where both exist

Tags: r, vector, correlation

Using R, I wish to:
Take two time series:

```
a<-c(NA,1,2,3,NA,5)
b<-c(0,NA,6,7,NA,NA)
```

I would like to end up with

```
aa<-c(2,3), bb<-(6,7)
```

or alternately

```
aa<-c(NA,NA,2,3,NA,NA)
```

The genesis for this question lies in 'feature' of the **ccf/acf** function in R.  The mean of a series is calculated prior to checking for the existance of mutual data points. The default fails on NA values, but if **na.action=na.pass**, this can result in correlation coeficients greater than one.
Although my actual data are time series, I am not currently interested in time lagged ACF, I am only interested in spatial cross correlation between disparate data sets, so the loss of absolute temporal data inherent in this  approach is not important. I wish to run the CCF with vetors in which the unusable data has already been 'knocked out'

The actual data sets are ~ 10,000 points each x 20 sets

Thank you in advance for advice

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard subsetting and `is.na` to find where both have non NA elements.

```
a[!is.na(a)&!is.na(b)]
[1] 2 3
b[!is.na(a)&!is.na(b)]
[1] 6 7
```

Answer (score 1):

The question has already been answered by @James. You can create the alternative versions with the following commands:

```
idx <- ! (a + b) * 0
a[idx]
# [1] NA NA  2  3 NA NA
b[idx]
# [1] NA NA  6  7 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

```
index = !is.na(a) & !is.na(b)
aa = a[index]
bb = b[index]
```

Answer (score 0):

**1)** Combine them both into a data.frame, remove rows with any NAs in them and then extract back out what is left:

```
both <- data.frame(a, b)
both <- na.omit(both) ##
aa <- both$a
bb <- both$b
```

To get the representation with NAs in it replace the second line (marked with ##) with:

```
both[is.na(rowSums(both), ] <- NA
```

**2)** Alternately consider a time series representation:

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(cbind(a, b))
z <- na.omit(z) ##
aa.z <- z$a
bb.z <- z$b
```

To get the repesentation with NAs in it replace the second line (marked with ##) with:

```
z[is.na(rowSums(both))] <- NA
```

**3)** The representation with NAs in the output could also be done using `"ts"` class:

```
tt <- ts(cbind(a, b))
tt[is.na(rowSums(both))] <- NA
aa.ts <- tt[, "a"]
bb.ts <- tt[, "b"]
```

*Note:* Depending on how you use the them afterwards you might not need to extract them out at the end, i.e. you might not need the last two lines in each solution.

*ADDED* additional solutions.